# Is there a way to get slide-in menu in ios app while using iPad on the landscape mode?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

Currently I am calling a popover segue to the menu which does not be slid-in or out with swiping action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're currently using https://github.com/ECSlidingViewController/ECSlidingViewController, there are some other libarries that we've tried but this one works best on various screen sizes and both portrait/landscape modes. It is pretty easy to customize the transitions too.